# extract information from Twitters anonymous search page

Tags: python, parsing, twitter, beautifulsoup

Considering [the call limits of Twitter API](https://blog.twitter.com/official/en_us/a/2008/what-does-rate-limit-exceeded-mean-updated.html), I am looking for possibilities to get search results without having an account/app. I have realized that this URL

```
https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&q=<keyWord1>%20<keyWord2>%20<keyWord3>&src=typd&lang=en
```

where `<keyWord1>%20<keyWord2>%20<keyWord3>` are the search queries, indeed  returns a page (for [example this](https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&q=python%20java%20julia&src=typd&lang=en)) including the information scrambled in the HTML format:

```
<div class="js-tweet-text-container">
<p class="TweetTextSize  js-tweet-text tweet-text" lang="en" data-aria-label-part="0">tweetText..</p>
</div>
```

I can extract the page using this snippet:

```
#%%
import requests 

def srch(*keyWords):
    string = "%20".join(keyWords)
    url = 'https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&q=' + string + '&src=typd&lang=en'
    return requests.get(url)
```

Now my questions are:

1. what is the best way to extract these information? using regular expressions `re` module or `BeautifulSoup`...?
2. what information can be extracted? Tweet's text, user-ID/name, time-date, number of likes-retweets-comments are visible in that page and should be probably extractable?
3. how many tweets can be extracted at one request or certain time span? is there any rate limit for example for the `request` module to call that page and extract the HTML? Is it possible that they block certain IPs?

I would appreciate if you could give an example of how this should be done.

Comment: Twitter's terms of service prohibit scraping the website, and the service will block IP addresses that are found to be doing that. You could take a look at the [full archive search API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/overview/premium) instead, which is the proper programmatic method to use for this.

Comment: aha, Ok. but what is the limit? how many requests can one have per hour without getting blocked for example?

Answer (score 1):

Try Kenneth Reitz package Twitter-scraper(https://github.com/kennethreitz/twitter-scraper). You get to scrape Twitter without the fuzz.

Btw: Kenneth is the author of requests packages. Everything he makes is awesome.

Comment: awsome. I was just looking into the request package to do it from scratch.

Comment: ok. looking into the [source code](https://github.com/kennethreitz/twitter-scraper/blob/master/twitter_scraper.py) it seems it just returns tweets for a specific user not a search query as I want. plus it cant distinguish between retweets and original ones, though non relevant to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. it easy using `beautifulsoup` but faster using `re` but it maybe harder to do.
2. what information will you can get just see in `li.js-stream-item`
3. it can extract 20 tweet without pagination

example code

```
tweets = soup.select('li.js-stream-item')
for tweet in tweets:
   name = tweet.select_one('FullNameGroup strong')
   text = tweet.select_one('p.TweetTextSize')
   timeStamp = tweet.select_one('a.tweet-timestamp').get('title')
```